# Solidify outline not working correctly

Tags: solidify-modifier

So I tried to set up an outline, however, this happened. Ignore the bits with clothes, but the rest (head, hair and right arm) don't have the outline. How do I fix this?

[image: Outline not showing on multiple parts of body]

Comment: It seems you have multiple modifiers. Have you tried changing their orders ? 
Please add your blend file so we can better understand the behavior you have in the file

Comment: Sure! My wifi's terrible so I have actually been trying to upload it for a while. Also, yes I have tried changing the orders of the modifiers.

Comment: i have no idea how you made your "outline", but if you made it via grease pencil, be aware that the outline will only be painted correctly if you look through your camera.

Comment: @Pineapple, depending on the way you create your outline effects, if it is with a mesh, have you try reverting or recomputing normals?

Comment: @B.Pader Thanks so much! this worked perfectly, I can't believe I didn't think about this sooner heh.